# Can't insert to database because of foreign key constraints

Tags: c#, sql-server, deserialization

I'm working on a project where deserialize XML and map it to a XML to a database and it works perfectly until it comes to the foreign column.

I have a bunch of personal information of different people on a XML and I want to read these to the database. There is just one tag that doesn't work and the reason is because it's a foreign key.

I get error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Seamen_UnregistrationReason". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Bums", table "dbo.UnregistrationReason", column 'Code'.

Here is the code that I'm using:

Here I deserialize the XML

```
  List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE> deserializedList = new List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>();
    deserializedList = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>();

    var myPersons = Deserialize<List<FolkbokforingspostTYPE>>()
        .Select(x => new Person
        {
            PersonalIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.PersonNr,
            SpecialIdentityNumber = x.Personpost.PersonId.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering != null ? x.Personpost.PersonId.Tilltalsnamnsmarkering : null, 
            LastName = x.Personpost.Namn.Efternamn,
            FirstName = x.Personpost.Namn.Fornamn,
            NationalRegistrationCountyCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.LanKod,
            NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = x.Personpost.Folkbokforing.KommunKod,
            NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress1 : null,
            NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Utdelningsadress2 : null,
            NationalRegistrationPostCode = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.PostNr : null,

            UnregistrationReason = x.Personpost.Avregistrering != null ? x.Personpost.Avregistrering.AvregistreringsorsakKod : null,
            UnregistrationDate = x.Personpost.Avregistrering != null ? x.Personpost.Avregistrering.Avregistreringsdatum : null,

            NationalRegistrationCity = x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress != null ? x.Personpost.Adresser.Folkbokforingsadress.Postort : null,
            BirthCountyCode = x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige != null ? x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige.FodelselanKod : null,
            BirthParish = x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige != null ? x.Personpost.Fodelse.HemortSverige.Fodelseforsamling : null,
            CitizenshipDate = x.Personpost.Medborgarskap != null ? x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.Medborgarskapsdatum : null,

            CitizenshipCode = x.Personpost.Medborgarskap.MedborgarskapslandKod,

            // and so on
        });
```

Here I read it into the database

```
string connetionString = null;


        SqlDataAdapter adpter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XmlReader xmlFile;



        connetionString = "Data Source=tsrv2062;Initial Catalog=Bums;User ID=BumsUser;Password=2tusen7Bums";


        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("navetout.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
        {
            connection.Open();



            DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;

            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1, NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2, UnregistrationReason = @UnregistrationReason, UnregistrationDate = @UnregistrationDate, NationalRegistrationPostCode = @NationalRegistrationPostCode,NationalRegistrationCity = @NationalRegistrationCity, BirthCountyCode = @BirthCountyCode, BirthParish = @BirthParish, CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber", connection);

            foreach (Person p in myPersons)
            {

                command1.Parameters.Clear();
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", p.NationalRegistrationCountyCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", p.NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1", p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationPostCode", p.NationalRegistrationPostCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCity", p.NationalRegistrationCity ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthCountyCode", p.BirthCountyCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", p.UnregistrationReason ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationDate", p.UnregistrationDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthParish", p.BirthParish ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", p.CitizenshipCode);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", p.CitizenshipDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", datum);



                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));


            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");


        }// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
       catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here I get error on the:
`command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", p.UnregistrationReason ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());`

Here is my class to store the values

```
class Person {
       public string PersonalIdentityNumber { get; set; }
       public string SpecialIdentityNumber { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationCountyCode { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationPostCode { get; set; }
       public string NationalRegistrationCity { get; set; }
       public string BirthCountyCode { get; set; }
       public string BirthParish { get; set; }
       public string CitizenshipDate { get; set; }
       public string UnregistrationReason { get; set; }
       public string UnregistrationDate { get; set; }
       public string CitizenshipCode { get; set; }
}
```

As I said, this used to work before including the column `UnregistrationReason` which is a foreign key.

I'm reading multiple persons personal information into the database. Not all the persons have `UnregistrationReason`. I get the error when trying to insert the `UnregistrationReason` when there is no such column in the XML where I'm deserialize from. If that is the case, it should just skip it and move on but instead I'm getting that error.

It IS possible to include the `UnregistrationReason` IF all the persons have the `UnregistrationReason`in their personal information, but in this case not all does and I want it to just skip it if that person is missing on that information.

**My goal:** I want the code to skip the `UnregistrationReason` when deserializing and inserting to the database **if** there is no such value in the XML.

I hope you understood what I want to achieve and please ask me if you have any questions.

Comment: What happens if you just skip the row                 _command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", p.UnregistrationReason ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());_ when _UnregistrationReason_ is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the `UnregistrationReason` out of the sql query if you don't have it or don't want to update it. For example:

```
String sql="UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1, NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2, UnregistrationDate = @UnregistrationDate, NationalRegistrationPostCode = @NationalRegistrationPostCode,NationalRegistrationCity = @NationalRegistrationCity, BirthCountyCode = @BirthCountyCode, BirthParish = @BirthParish, CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate";

if(HaveUnregistrationReason)
    sql += ", UnregistrationReason = @UnregistrationReason";
sql += " WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

if(HaveUnregistrationReason)
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", p.UnregistrationReason ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that might work. However, as you can see I have 
 `SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query)` How can I add on that if the condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First make sure that the table column accepts null values.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.UnregistrationReason))
    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", p.UnregistrationReason);
```

Otherwise, remove the foreign key constraint.